# Is the localization of an injective cogenerator an injective cogenerator?

Tags: commutative-algebra

We know that in Noetherian rings any localization of an injective module is again an injective module.  Is the localization of any injective cogenerator again injective cogenerator?

Comment: This is a little more trivial than Eric Wofsey's response, but if you are asking whether, if $M$ is an injective cogenerator in the category of $R$-modules, then $M_S$ is an injective cogenerator in the category of $R_S$-modules, then the answer is still no, because $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not.  For instance, over $\mathbb{Z}$, if you localize any module with respect to the multiplicative set $\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, you get a $\mathbb{Q}$-module.  A $\mathbb{Q}$-module can never be a cogenerator, since no torsion module can map nontrivially to it.

If you ask only for the localization to be a cogenerator for modules over the localized ring, then as Slade commented, this is still not true.  For instance, $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is an injective cogenerator over $\mathbb{Z}$, but $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Q}=0$ is not an injective cogenerator over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helping